# I get "500 Backend Error" and "400 invalidMetadata" from youtube-api

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I use PHP to insert/update the title and description of our video by using youtube-api and I get some problems with it.

1.
When I insert/update title and description of video by using zh-Hant or zh-Hans, I get `"500 Backend Error."`
However it works when I change `zh-Hant` and `zh-Hans` to `zh-tw` and `zh-cn`.

[500 Backend Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsL4.png)

[image]

2.
I get `"400 invalidMetadata"` when I update a video title by using Italian(it).
I have no idea about this because it's all fine in others languages and it also fine in update video description by using Italian.

[400 invalidMetadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40K7K.png)

[image]

How can I fix these problems?

Here is my code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('key/youtube_key/client_secret.json'));
    $client->setApplicationName("String System");
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAccessToken(Cache::get('google_auth_token'));

    $this->client = $client;
}

public function youtubeService($stringKey, $stringValue, $language)
{
    $this->service = new \Google_Service_YouTube($this->client);

    $this->stringKey = $stringKey;
    $this->stringValue = $stringValue;
    $this->language = $language;

    $key = explode('_', $this->stringKey);
    if (3 != count($key)) {
        return;
    }

    list($videoName, $videoID, $type) = $key;
    $this->videoName= $videoName;
    $this->videoID = $videoID;

    switch ($type) {
        case 'title':
            $this->updateTitle();
            break;

        case 'description':
            $this->updateDesc();
            break;
    }

    return;
}

private function updateTitle()
{
    // get video list by video ID
    $video = $this->service->videos->listVideos(
        'snippet,localizations',
        ['id' => $this->videoID]
    );
    $videoInfo = $video->items[0];

    // set video title of language
    if (isset($videoInfo->localizations[$this->language])) {
        $videoInfo->localizations[$this->language]->title =
                $this->stringValue;

        // check default language
        if ($this->language === $videoInfo->snippet->defaultLanguage) {
            $videoInfo->snippet->title = $this->stringValue;
        }
    } else {
        $videoInfo->localizations[$this->language] = [
            'title' => $this->stringValue,
            'description' => 'description'
        ];
    }

    try {
        // update video information
        $this->service->videos->update(
            'snippet,localizations',
            $videoInfo
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // do nothing and continue
    }

    return;
}

private function updateDesc()
{
    // get video list by video ID
    $video = $this->service->videos->listVideos(
        'snippet,localizations',
        ['id' => $this->videoID]
    );
    $videoInfo = $video->items[0];

    // set video description of language
    if (isset($videoInfo->localizations[$this->language])) {
        $videoInfo->localizations[$this->language]->description =
                $this->stringValue;

        // check default language
        if ($this->language === $videoInfo->snippet->defaultLanguage) {
            $videoInfo->snippet->description = $this->stringValue;
        }
    } else {
        $videoInfo->localizations[$this->language] = [
            'title' => 'title',
            'description' => $this->stringValue
        ];
    }

    try {
        // update video information
        $this->service->videos->update(
            'snippet,localizations',
            $videoInfo
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // do nothing and continue
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we cant help you debug what we cant see.

Comment: I update my code. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: Does anyone has some solutions to help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the language that you used (zh-Hant & zh-Hans) is not supported as of the moment.

To verify whether a language is supported or not, you may utilize i18nLanguages.list API.  Here's a sample request using API explorer.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.i18nLanguages.list?part=snippet&_h=1&

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. This solve a my first problem.
But, the second is uncanny because "it" throws error of "invalidMetadata" to me. 
How can I solve this problem?